# Помогите построить рекурсию на Java

Tags: рекурсия, java, алгоритм

Задача: есть строка вида

> (zzzz (аааа "bbbb1 bbbb2" (ccccc "dddd1 dddd2" (eeeee)) ffff (gggg hhhh) iiiii jjjj))

необходимо написать на джаве программу-рекурсию, которая переводит такой список в `ArrayList` с многоуровенной вложенностью, т.е. встреченная в строке скобка - это углубление на уровень, элемент аррэйлиста сам становится аррейлистом и т.д., например в данной примерной строке на верхнем уровне два элемента: zzzz и аррэйлист в составе aaaa bbbb еще аррей лист из cccc dddd и так далее...
*Строки в кавычках должны быть взяты единым блоком, т.е. от кавычки до кавычки!*

Помогите, пожалуйста, с алгоритмом, а то мой вариант неправильно работает (на `Gson` не обращайте внимания):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parser {
String inputString;
String commandLine;

public Parser(String in,String com){
    this.inputString=in;
    this.commandLine=com;        
}

public String parse() {
    Gson json = new Gson();
    ArrayList result=getDevicesList();

    return json.toJson(result);
}

private ArrayList getDevicesList() {
    ArrayList result=getBracketBlock(0,this.inputString);
    return result;
}

private ArrayList getBracketBlock(int pos, String in) {
    ArrayList buffer = new ArrayList();
    String token = "";
    Boolean IS_STRING = false;
    String source = in.substring(pos);
    char [] chr = source.toCharArray();
    pos=0;
    while( chr[pos]!=')') {
        if( chr[pos]=='(' ) {
            buffer.add(getBracketBlock(pos+1,source.substring(pos)));

        }            
        if( chr[pos]==' ' && !token.equals(""))
        {
            if(!IS_STRING) {
                buffer.add(token);System.out.println(token+" "+pos);
                token="";                    
            }
        } 
        if(chr[pos]=='\"') IS_STRING=!IS_STRING;
        token+=chr[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    buffer.add(token);
    return buffer;
}
}
```

Comment: даю совет пока что... сядь напиши алгоритм на бумаге, раскрась фломастерами, пойми - запрограммируй

Comment: Gorets, как думаешь, зачем я здесь вопрос создал?.. Мне помощь нужна, а не фломастеры!!!

Comment: @deivan - быстрая помощь это на фриланс :)

Comment: ребяты, вы так здорово мне помогаете, земной вам поклон, что бы без вас делал

Comment: ну например я бы помог.. но не все же делать за тебя.. я кстати, только что попробовал написать.. пока что быстро нечего не получается и мне не нравится тут использовать рекурсию, лучше конечный автомат. Или просто таким вот способом... 

                String[] strings = "(zzzz (аааа bbbb (ccccc ddddd (eeeee)) ffff (gggg hhhh) iiiii jjjj))".split(" ");
                for (String s: strings) {

Comment: о, кстати вот первый конструктивный комментарий, - я забыл добавить, что среди блоков строчек есть строчки вида "аааа1 аааа2 аааа3", т.е. вариант со спритом по спейсу не подходит, там в коде видно - я отлавливаю строки по кавычкам как единое целое.

Comment: ищешь первую скобку в строке, как нашел - ищешь последнюю.... все, что между ними - передаешь в рекурсию...

String[] string = "(zzzz (аааа bbbb (ccccc ddddd (eeeee)) ffff (gggg hhhh) iiiii jjjj))";

for(int i = 0;i<string.length;i++){

    if(string.charAt(i) == '('){

     for(int j = string.length-1;j-- ){

        if(string.charAt(j) == ')'){

           <передаешь в рекурсию строку между i и j

Comment: тут не так все просто, - это работает когда (aaa (bbb ccc) ddd), т.е. только вложенные простые объекты есть, а затык у меня случился в построении корректной обрабтки такого случая: (aaa (bbb ccc (ddd eee))), т.е. уровни вложенности нужно также обработать - создать соответствующий аррэйлист.. задачка не так легка, как кажется на первый взгляд..

Comment: JSON? не, не слышал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, отвечаю сам себе. Вот рабочий код, который решают мою задачу:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parser {
String inputString;
String commandLine;
int pos;

public Parser(String in,String com){
    this.inputString=in;
    this.commandLine=com;
    this.pos=0;
}

public String parse() {
    return getDevicesList().toString();
}

private ArrayList getDevicesList() {       
    ArrayList result=getBracketBlock();
    return result;
}

private ArrayList getBracketBlock() {
    ArrayList buffer = new ArrayList();
    String token = "";
    Boolean IS_STRING = false;
    char [] chr = this.inputString.toCharArray();
    while( pos<inputString.length()-1) {

        if(chr[pos]==' ' && !IS_STRING) {
            if(!token.equals("") && !token.equals(" ") && !token.equals("  ")) {
                buffer.add(token.trim());
                token="";
                pos++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(chr[pos]==')' && !IS_STRING) {
            if(!token.equals("") && !token.equals(" ")) buffer.add(token);
            break;
        } 
        if(chr[pos]=='(') {
            pos++;
            buffer.add(getBracketBlock());
            pos++;
            continue;
        }
        if(chr[pos]=='\"') IS_STRING=!IS_STRING;

        token+=chr[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    return buffer;
}
}
```

Не идеальное, но вполне рабочее решение, которое иллюстрирует решение задач на парсинг списочных данных. 
Надеюсь, этот алгоритм поможет в будущем кому-нибудь из посетителей форума.
Пусть повисит вопрос открытым до конца дня, для конструктивных комментариев, потом - закрою.
Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: String token = "";
... 
        if(chr[pos]==' ' && !IS_STRING) {
            if(!token.equals("") && !token.equals(" ") && !token.equals("  ")) {
                buffer.add(token.trim());
                token="";


аццкий код, читаю - если позиция равняется пробелу (hr[pos]==' ') и не равняется не 1 непробелу, не 2м, не 3.. подозреваю, что-то тут не то... зачем 2й if?

Comment: getDevicesList() - лишний, зачем getBracketBlock() оборачивать в  getDevicesList()?

Comment: ничего аццкого, все православно :) 
смотрите внимательно: chr[] это массив с исходной строкой, token - это текущее слово, которое набирается посимвольно и затем добавляется в аррейлист. 
но где-то я проспал, и иногда токен остается пустым или просто один пробел - а такого в наборе быть не должно. поэтому я и проверяю, чтобы в набор не шли пустые или пробельные токены.(это второй иф)
вместе с тем, пробелы допустимы, если токен - строка, т.е. состоит из нескольких слов, для етого есть флаг ИЗ_СТРИНГ (первый иф)

Comment: ну а насчет двойного обертывания - это не важно, поскольку в проекте, для которого решается эта задача, есть несколько источников таких строк, и для каждого источника будет свой класс парсинга всего-то

Comment: ну хорошо, что справился с задачей, но я бы рекомендовал, если есть  время, почитать информацию про конечные автоматы, они лучше справляются с такими задачами и не делают такой путаницы...

Answer (score 0):

```
String strings = "(zzzz (аааа bbbb (ccccc ddddd (eeeee)) ffff (gggg hhhh) iiiii jjjj))";

int i = 0;
while (i < strings.length()) {
    i++;
    if (strings.charAt(i) == '(') {

    }
    if (strings.charAt(i) == ')') {

    }
}
```

попробуй как-то так...

Comment: угу. масло масляное. а рекурсия где?

Comment: так в том то и дело.. где тут рекурсия? т.е. как тут применить ее? я например не вижу смысла.. или тебе надо именно рекурсией его сделать? расскажи нам как эта рекурсия тут должна работать...

Comment: в моем примере кода есть рекурсия, только она выводит бред, не могу понять где я ошибся.
насчет смысла рекурсии очевидно же - код, который ловит список в скобках - он типичен, его нужно написать и использовать рекурсивно для всей строки.